# Inquiry of an 'American' company?

Tags: business

I'm dealing with an investment company that claims to be an 'American' company but is registered at BVI (British Virgin Island).  I can't find any physical U.S. address at its website and it is the subsidiary company of a ShenZhen, China based company.  How could I verify further it is truly an American company?

Comment: 99% sure you are getting into a scam trap. I get these "we would like to invest in your business" scam emails on a regular basis. Please cease all contact (the longer you engage, the more vulnerable you are) or direct them to a lawyer.

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by "an American company". Registered as a corporation in some US state? Has a physical presence in the US?

Answer (score -1):

The [British Virgin Islands](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Virgin_Islands) are in the Caribbean Sea and are therefore “American” as are all countries in the continents of North and South America.

The United States of America is a country in the Americas, but the USA is **not** the only American country, just like China is not the only Asian country. It is perfectly valid for a company based in the BVI to describe itself as American just as it would be for a Canadian, Peruvian or Cuban company.

That said, this is likely a scam.

Comment: No offense, but the company was clearly trying to sound like it was in the U.S.

Comment: It might be valid in a narrow sense to say Cuba was "in America" but would obviously be very very misleading. I agree that it is likely a scam.

Answer (score -4):

You can check the company out with FINRA to see if they are registered. It's as simple as that.
https://www.finra.org/investors/investment-advisers

Comment: FINRA seems to deal with registered broker/dealers. I do not think this will be helpful to the poster. You not find large venture capital companies like New Enterprise Associates or Sequoia Capitol mentioned on FINRA.

Comment: VCs give you money, instead of managing yours @GeorgeWhite. They don't fall under the same FINRA rules. FINRA is mainly for banks.

Comment: You can read about it here. @GeorgeWhite https://www.strictlybusinesslawblog.com/2018/05/31/the-venture-capital-adviser-exemption-explained/

Comment: right - FINRA has nothing to do with investment companies but with broker dealers. The question was about an investment company so pointing them to FINRA seems to not be useful.

Comment: Investment here refers to investing the person's money. They aren't calling him from to invest in him.

Comment: More downvotes for no reason. It's so old.

Comment: Yes they are calling to invest in him. The question doesn't seem to indicate which direction the "investment" would be going but a scammer would often say they want to invest in your company or otherwise send you money. That is what  gets the victim's attention. Regarding downvotes - I think you have ample written feedback regarding perceived defects in some of your answers

Comment: So you are insisting I am wrong with no evidence and downvoting? lol

Comment: Your answer was essentially that the OPs problem could be solved by looking at a single website that covers registered broker/dealers. Yes, that is not a very good answer.  I did not actually downvote the answer until just now.

Comment: So looking at a database of American companies that operate in that space is wrong, but someone saying "American" does not refer to the U.S. is ok? Quit your ridiculous downvotes on my posts please.

Comment: I'm the one who upvoted your comment about the answer regarding "America".

Comment: But you downvoted this answer right?

Comment: not at first, but yes, I was the second downvote a few minutes ago.